# Can I create an iterable of mixed primitives and Strings?

Tags: java

I want to create a character deliminated string using the Apache commons library.

`StringUtils.join(java.lang.Iterable,char)`

If my objects are

```
int a = 1;
boolean b = true;
String c = "hello world";
```

How can I put them all in an `<iterable>` so that I can pass them into the `join` method?

Comment: Use `Object` for the type. `boolean` will be boxed in a `Boolean` instance. All objects are proper subtypes of `Object`, and every primitive has a wrapper class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Object` as the type.

```
List<Object> list = Arrays.<Object>asList(1, true, "hello world");
```

Here the primitives have been autoboxed to the corresponding reference types.

**Edit**

I put the `.<Object>` in because I was told in the comments that my answer didn't compile. I have since tried it and

```
List<Object> list = Arrays.asList(1, true, "hello world");
```

does compile for me (I'm using jdk1.8.0_25). They must have recently improved type inference.

Comment: Nice use of autoboxing. Could use a little prose.

Comment: Cheers, thanks for the update. Can you explain the .<Object> part?

Comment: The compiler isn't able to infer the type from those 3 arguments so you have to explicitly tell it the type you want. To be honest I don't really know why it can't do whatever the diamond operator manages to do.

Comment: Cool, yeah the second version doesn't work for `1.7.0_40-b43`.

Comment: @dwjohnston Java 8 is brilliant. Streams are amazing. Update now!